# Javascript - Some errors in my LocalStorage script

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am a newbie in JS (level 0), and although I try to store all the variables of my practice in Local Storage, I am doing something wrong, because when reloading the page many functions (previously visible), now disappear in the reload.

**[SEE LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/43q90jzv/5/)**

Where is my errors...?
What am I doing wrong...?

Thanks in advance!

**CSS**

```
html{top:0;left:0;margin:0}body{top:0;margin:0;padding:0;color:#323232;width:100%;height:100%;line-height:1.5;font-family:'Roboto',serif}#container{width:500px;margin:0 auto}#container p{display:inline-block;margin-top:20px}#productos{display:none}.img-prod{display:inline-block;float:left;margin-right:10px}.img-prod img{width:100%;height:auto;max-width:70px;display:block;border:0}#comp-p1,#comp-p2,#comp-p3{width:120px;height:30px;margin-top:15px;background:green;padding:10px 0 5px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;color:#fff;cursor:pointer}.derecha{border:solid 1px #999;max-height:400px;width:350px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;padding:10px 0;overflow-y:auto;float:right}#producto-1,#producto-2,#producto-3{display:inline-block;width:220px;padding:10px;float:left;text-align:left;font-size:.9em;margin-right:5px}#producto-1{background:green;color:#fff}#producto-2{background:#add8e6;color:#000}#producto-3{background:#666;color:#fff}.cont-p{display:inline-block;margin:7px auto;line-height:1}.bbp{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:24px;height:24px;text-align:center;background:red;color:#fff;margin-left:5px;line-height:1.5;cursor:pointer}.cont-num{float:left;width:24px;height:24px;margin:20px 5px 0 20px;padding:4px 3px 3px;background:red;text-align:center;font-size:16px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#fff}#mostrar{display:none;width:100px;margin:70px 0 0;padding:10px;text-align:center;background:grey;color:#fff;cursor:pointer}.derecha input{width:0;height:0;border:none;visibility:hidden}#cont-resultado{text-align:center;width:110px;margin-top:70px;background:grey;padding:5px 10px 10px;color:#fff}#cont-resultado input{display:inline-block;margin:10px auto;background:#fff;color:#000;border:1px solid #000;padding:8px 0}#cont-resultado p{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;background:grey;padding:8px 10px;cursor:pointer}#total{display:block;width:80px;text-align:center}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="productos">

    <!-- ============================================== -->

    <div id="cont-p1" class="cont-p">
      <div id="producto-1">
        <div class="img-prod"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Lichtenstein_img_processing_test.png"> </div>cont-p1 cloned!<br><br>Input Value = 1</div>

      <input class="add-prod" type="num" value="1">

      <div class="bbp">X</div>
    </div>

    <!-- ============================================== -->

    <div id="cont-p2" class="cont-p">
      <div id="producto-2">
        <div class="img-prod"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Lichtenstein_img_processing_test.png"></div>
        cont-p2 cloned!<br><br>Input Value = 1</div>

      <input class="add-prod" type="num" value="1">

      <div class="bbp">X</div>
    </div>

    <!-- ============================================== -->

    <div id="cont-p3" class="cont-p">
      <div id="producto-3">
        <div class="img-prod"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Lichtenstein_img_processing_test.png"></div>
        cont-p3 cloned!<br><br>Input Value = 198</div>

      <input class="add-prod" type="num" value="198">

      <div class="bbp">X</div>
    </div>

    <!-- ============================================== -->

  </div><!-- // productos -->

  <div class="derecha"></div>

  <div id="comp-p1" onClick="clickME();clickME2();">Clone 1</div>
  <div id="comp-p2" onClick="clickME();clickME2();">Clone 2</div>
  <div id="comp-p3" onClick="clickME();clickME2();">Clone 3</div>

  <div class="cont-num" id="clicks">0</div>
  <div class="cont-num" id="clicksdos">0</div>

  <div id="cont-resultado">
    <input name="total" id="total">
    Total of sum
  </div>

</div>
<!-- // container -->

<script>
// Script que suma y resta los clicks

  var clicks = 0;

  function clickME() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks
  }
  var clicksdos = 0;

  function clickME2() {
    clicksdos += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML = clicksdos;

    if (clicksdos === 1) {
      document.getElementById("cont-resultado").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  if (clicksdos === 0) {
    document.getElementById("cont-resultado").style.display = "none";
  }

  function restar() {
    if (clicks > 0) clicks -= 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  }

  function restardos() {
    if (clicksdos > 0) clicksdos -= 1;
    document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML = clicksdos;
    if (clicksdos === 0) {
      document.getElementById("cont-resultado").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
// Script for clone the div´s

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#comp-p1").click(function() {
    $("#cont-p1").clone().appendTo(".derecha");
    localStorage.setItem("html",document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML); // New
    displaySuma();
  });
  // =============
  $("#comp-p2").click(function() {
    $("#cont-p2").clone().appendTo(".derecha");
    localStorage.setItem("html",document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML); // New
    displaySuma();
  });
  // =============
  $("#comp-p3").click(function() {
    $("#cont-p3").clone().appendTo(".derecha");
    localStorage.setItem("html",document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML); // New
    displaySuma();
  });
});

const getParent = (match, node) => (node.matches(match)) ? node : getParent(match, node.parentNode);

// Deal with remove
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let target = event.target;
  if (target.matches('.bbp')) {
    restar();
    restardos();
    getParent('.derecha', target).removeChild(target.parentNode);
    localStorage.setItem("html",document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML); // New
    displaySuma();
  }
})

// New Script for sum inputs
const displaySuma = () => document.getElementById("total").value = suma();

const suma = function() {
  let x = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".derecha div .add-prod"));
  let sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    sum += parseFloat(x[i].value);
  }
  console.log(sum);
  return sum;
  localStorage.setItem("html",document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML); // New
}
//console.log(suma());
document.getElementById("total").value = suma();

// New

if ((localStorage.getItem("clicks")!=null) && (localStorage.getItem("clicksdos")!=null))
  {
    clicks=parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clicks"));
    clicksdos=parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clicksdos"));
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks;
    document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML=clicksdos;
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("html")!=null)
  {
    document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("html")
  }

//});
```

Comment: On you `if` for localStorage you need to call `displaySuma` once you have loaded everything. Also rememeber, `localStorage` is NOT available in every browser, so you need a `if(localStorage)`

Comment: The truth, Bibberty, is that I want to give up. I can not implant it .... and that it works for me... :( ...

Comment: Hang in there. You need to learn to break things into simpler units of work.

Comment: I need to learn JS. I'm stuck with LocalStorage...

Comment: Take a look here, all fixed up and working: https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/ForPablo

Comment: Hey, Bibberty, very interesting! Question: Now how can I hide the gray box "Result", when the click counters are at zero...?

Comment: Sorted that also, notice how with methods it was easy to add.

Comment: At first it seems that it does work, but the click counter appears initially at "1", even though there is no clone into "derecha". How I can fix this...?

Comment: It is due to `old` localStorage data. Clear your cache.

Comment: I added a fix for it anyway, try now.

Comment: OK, Bibberty, wonderful! I was editing with you at JSF. See here ( https://jsfiddle.net/aejhxm8s/2/ )

Comment: I'm going to study this in depth because I understand that it's not complex or difficult, I just have to know where to place the strings and after make the calls back (now your script is something different, but cleaner). Your help is great, friend. Thank you very much for your time and dedication to the community of novices like me. Cheers!. Thanks again, Bibberty. Regards...

Comment: Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version using `localStorage` unfortunately snippets does not allow use of `localStorage`.

Because of this, here is a version of the [code running in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aejhxm8s/2/)

```js
let clicks = 0;
let clicksdos = 0;

const safeInt = (key) => {
  let value = parseInt(getValue(key));
  return (isNaN(value) || value < 0) ? 0 : value;
}

// This loads our clicks from the LocalStorage
const loadClicks = () => {
  clicks = safeInt('clicks');
  clicksdos = safeInt('clicksdos');
}

const loadHTML = () => {
  return getValue('html', '');
}

const loadFromStorage = () => {
  let html = loadHTML();
  if (html !== '') {
    loadClicks();
  }
  displayClicks();
  document.querySelector(".derecha").innerHTML = html;
}

// Display the clicks on the screen
const displayClicks = () => {
  clicks = (clicks === NaN) ? 0 : clicks;
  clicksdos = (clicksdos === NaN) ? 0 : clicksdos;
  document.querySelector('#clicks').innerHTML = clicks;
  document.querySelector('#clicksdos').innerHTML = clicksdos;
  // Hide / Show Result 
  let display = (clicks > 0) ? 'block' : 'none';
  document.querySelector('#cont-resultado').style.display = display;
}

const adjustClicks = (value) => {
  clicks += value;
  clicksdos += value;
  storeValue('clicks', clicks);
  storeValue('clicksdos', clicksdos);
  displayClicks();
}
const addClick = () => adjustClicks(1);
const removeClick = () => adjustClicks(-1);


// Manage localStorage
const storeValue = (key, value) => (localStorage) ? localStorage.setItem(key, value) : '';
const getValue = (key, defaultValue) => (localStorage) ? localStorage.getItem(key) : defaultValue;
const storeHTML = () => storeValue("html", document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML);

// Add a node to the Derecha
const addToDerecha = (nodeId) => {
  let node = document.querySelector(`#${nodeId}`);
  document.querySelector('.derecha').appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
  storeHTML();
  displaySuma();
};

// Monitor ALL click events 
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let target = event.target;
  // Add
  if (target.matches('.comp-clone')) {
    addClick();
    addToDerecha(event.target.dataset.clone);
  }
  // Remove
  if (target.matches('.bbp')) {
    removeClick();
    getParent('.derecha', target).removeChild(target.parentNode);
    storeHTML();
    displaySuma();
  }
});

// This is just a helper function.
const getParent = (match, node) => (node.matches(match)) ? node : getParent(match, node.parentNode);

// New Script for sum inputs
const displaySuma = () => document.getElementById("total").value = suma();

const suma = function() {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".derecha div .add-prod"))
    .reduce((a, v) => a + parseFloat(v.value), 0);
}

// Code to run when the document loads.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (localStorage) {
    loadFromStorage();
  }

  displaySuma();

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #323232;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

#container p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline
}

#productos {
  display: none
}

.img-prod {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.img-prod img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 70px;
  display: block;
  border: 0
}

#comp-p1,
#comp-p2,
#comp-p3 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer
}

.derecha {
  border: solid 1px #999;
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  float: right
}

#producto-1,
#producto-2,
#producto-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin-right: 5px
}

#producto-1 {
  background: green;
  color: #fff
}

#producto-2 {
  background: #add8e6;
  color: #000
}

#producto-3 {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff
}

.cont-p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px auto;
  line-height: 1
}

.bbp {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 5px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  cursor: pointer
}

.cont-num {
  float: left;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 20px 5px 0 18px;
  padding: 4px 3px 3px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff
}

#mostrar {
  display: none
}

#mostrar {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 70px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer
}


/* ==== Style of Sume ==== */

.derecha input {
  width: 40px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px 0;
  padding: 2px 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center
}

#cont-resultado {
  text-align: center;
  width: 110px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px 10px 10px;
  color: #fff
}

#cont-resultado input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 8px 0
}

#cont-resultado p {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: grey;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  cursor: pointer
}

#total {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="productos">
      <!-- =============== -->
      <div id="cont-p1" class="cont-p">
        <div id="producto-1">
          <div class="img-prod"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Lichtenstein_img_processing_test.png"> </div>cont-p1 cloned!<br><br>Input Value = 1</div>

        <input class="add-prod" type="num" value="1">

        <div class="bbp">X</div>
      </div>
      <!-- =============== -->
      <div id="cont-p2" class="cont-p">
        <div id="producto-2">
          <div class="img-prod"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Lichtenstein_img_processing_test.png"></div>
          cont-p2 cloned!<br><br>Input Value = 1</div>

        <input class="add-prod" type="num" value="1">

        <div class="bbp">X</div>
      </div>
      <!-- =============== -->

      <div id="cont-p3" class="cont-p">
        <div id="producto-3">
          <div class="img-prod"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Lichtenstein_img_processing_test.png"></div>
          cont-p3 cloned!<br><br>Input Value = 198</div>

        <input class="add-prod" type="num" value="198">

        <div class="bbp">X</div>
      </div>
      <!-- =============== -->
    </div>
    <!-- // productos -->

    <div class="derecha"></div>

    <div id="comp-p1" data-clone="cont-p1" class="comp-clone">Clone 1</div>
    <div id="comp-p2" data-clone="cont-p2" class="comp-clone">Clone 2</div>
    <div id="comp-p3" data-clone="cont-p3" class="comp-clone">Clone 3</div>

    <div class="cont-num" id="clicks">0</div>
    <div class="cont-num" id="clicksdos">0</div>

    <div id="cont-resultado">
      <span>RESULT:</span><br>
      <input name="total" id="total">
      <br>Is the sum of the cloned divs
      <!--<p id='sumup'>Ver total</p>-->
    </div>

    <p><span>NOTE:</span><br>Here we are looking for only the cloned inputs can be sumed (and see the result in the box color gray).<br><br>The problem is that the current script does not apply a sume of the cloned inputs only... it adds ALL the inputs presents
      in the html...<br><br>So (1), how do you sum only the cloned inputs, ignoring those that are outside...?<br><br>And (2) also, how to subtract from the total result all the cloned divs that are deleted...?</p>

  </div>
  <!-- // container -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Many people will learn with this about LocalStorage secrets. Thanks Bibberty!

Comment: Bibberty ... There is a new problem in the script ( https://jsfiddle.net/aejhxm8s/2/ ), and maybe it would be nice to know how it is solved. You can only clone once every div and although the clone does not exist, the click counters keep increasing. It would be nice if the divs could be cloned indefinitely, as was the original script and retain the LocalStorage function, of course. What line of your script should I modify...?

Comment: Was missing `.cloneNode(true)` have added in the code above. Can you fix the jsFiddle.

Comment: Perfect! Now it's beautiful, clean and tidy ... The new jsFiddle is ( https://jsfiddle.net/u9dqzyxk/ ). Thanks again, Bibberty

Comment: Hi, Bibberty. Question: What is this Chrome console alert ...? ( Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'load' has already been declared at test.html:600 ). I have loaded your script into my project, which has other scripts, and nothing works. I have deleted all third-party scripts, to avoid interference, and it does not work in any browser. Only works on jsFiddle. Again: What is the Chrome console alert ...? Thanks. Regards.

Comment: It is because you already have a `function` or `variable` called `load` declared at the page level. Easy fix is to rename the `load` function in this code to something else.

Comment: I've removed all the "load" of other scripts and I've removed all third-party scripts, cleaned the browser's cache, etc., and now the Chrome alert does not come out, (it's clean and whitour errors), but it still does not work...

Comment: You do not need to remove everything. Just rename `load`

Comment: **Bibberty**, a new question. Is it possible to add the decimal point (for values ​​in thousands) to your script in the input `#total` ...? Above 999 the points are those used in Europe (1.000 / 2.000 / 3.000 ... etc), unlike other formats that use commas to separate the "thousands" (1,000 / 2,000 / 3,000 ...) ... What you think? ... I was looking to adapt this script to yours, but I could not do it ( https://jsfiddle.net/324hqmd8/ ) . Thanks. Regards...

Comment: **Bibberty** .. I have already solved the missing decimal point, with a very simple addition to your script on the line 139 `.toLocaleString("es-ES");` See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4bs5jtoy/1/

Comment: Great stuff. Good to hear

Comment: The credit is yours, **Bibberty**. It's your script... ;) ... One question: Why can't I solve this...? >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803333/javascript-detect-scroll-of-div-work-but-does-not-work