# Javascript - Detect scroll of div, work, but does not work

Tags: javascript

I have a design prototype in practices (I am a newbie in JS, level 0), and there is a problem in my script.

I am detecting if a div ( **#derecha** ), with fixed measurements (354px x 210px) triggers the scroll, and it works very well **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/m4r13wx8/)**, but I can not make it work **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/gfoLpr1t/)**, where some cloned divs are added ...

The div **#derecha** is commented on line 26 of CSS.

What am I doing wrong...?

**NOTE 1:** The prototype has LocalStorage. To test if it works, you have to empty the cache of your browser in each test.

**NOTE 2:** Please, see the CSS on line 37. It must be uncommented.

**NOTE 3:** The script that does not work for me is on line 177 of the HTML, and it's the same one that I publish below.

**[SEE DEMO LIVE](https://jsfiddle.net/gfoLpr1t/)** ( jsfiddle / Here it does not work if run snippet )

Thanks in advance!

```
// Displays the new product alert added when the scroll is detected in the div #derecha
var displaced = document.getElementById('derecha')
if (displaced.scrollHeight > displaced.offsetHeight) {
  document.getElementById("notice-product-added").style.display = "block";
};

// LocalStorage for the div #notice-product-added
const showMsgCart = localStorage.getItem('showMsgCarrito');

if (showMsgCart === 'false') {
  $('#notice-product-added').hide();
}
$('#notice-product-added').on('click', function() {
  $('#notice-product-added').fadeOut('slow');
  localStorage.setItem('showMsgCarrito', 'false');
});
```

Comment: Could you please give clear idea what exactly you are expecting to do? Do you want to scroll to end of div?

Comment: Hi **Tyler**. I do not want to move to the end of the div. I just want to show the div `# notice-product-added` when the `#derecha` div starts the scroll. The script of the publication (the same one of the line 177 in jsfiddle) detects the scroll, but in the LIVE DEMO ( https://jsfiddle.net/gfoLpr1t/ ) it does not work. I do not know why... But here yes works ( http://jsfiddle.net/m4r13wx8/ ) ...

Comment: **Tyler** Here ( http://jsfiddle.net/m4r13wx8/ ) you can comment the line 16 of the HTML, and Run the test ... Remember the LocalStorage!

Comment: Take a look here and try this: https://makandracards.com/makandra/12825-how-to-test-if-an-element-has-scrollbars-with-javascript-cucumber-step-inside

Comment: Are you just trying to have the div expand as more items are added? If so. Remove the max-height from `#derecha` and `.derecha`

Comment: **Bibberty** I do not want an expanded div. I want the div `.derecha` with scroll. This script perfectly detects the scroll (http://jsfiddle.net/m4r13wx8/), but it does not work in your script (https://jsfiddle.net/gfoLpr1t/). I will investigate other options...